# как добавить ScrollView для View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, view, scrollview

как добавить ScrollView внутри view Controller , я хочу, чтобы каждый элемент был прокручиваемым, так что с совместимостью с клавиатурой

Answer (score 0):

У вас всё-таки два вопроса и второй не очень связан с первым, поэтому отвечу на первый, а по движению клавиатуры с настроенным ScrollView информации в Интернете предостаточно (есть даже библиотеки, делающие всё за вас, например IQKeyboardManager).

Пусть у нас есть пустой VC и ScrollView должен занимать весь экран, скроллясь вертикально.
Тогда для того, чтобы полностью скроллить содержимое VC с полной поддержкой IB и Autolayout, необходимо проделать следующие шаги (описаны в TN2154 от Apple):

1. Устанавливаем constraints у ScrollView на края корневого view у ViewController'a. Важно, что констрейнты самого ScrollView не должны зависеть от его контента.
2. Внутрь ScrollView помещаем обычный UIView и ограничиваем его краями ScrollView. Это ключевой момент, отличающий Pure Autolayout Approach, описанный в TN2154, от остальных. На этом моменте IB может ругаться на недостаток констрейнтов, игнорируем это.
3. Весь наш контент располагаем внутри этого вложенного UIView, причем расположение должно позволить ScrollView однозначно вычислить свой вертикальный размер. Это означает, что самый верхний элемент должен быть ограничен верхней частью view, а самый нижний - нижней. Элементы c intrinsic content size (UILabel, UIImageView) должны быть ограничены во все стороны. Самостоятельно вычисляющих свой размер элементов, вроде UITableView, лучше избегать или строго ограничить их размеры с помощью height и width.

Если все шаги проделаны правильно, вы получите совместимый с Autolayout, редактируемый через IB ScrollView.